# How to programmatically get the installed game list in Android

Tags: java, android

In my project I can get the list of all installed application by the following code:

```
public class ApplicationFilterActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    ListView appfilter;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    public static String filenames = "RotateData";
PackageManager pck;
    ArrayList<Applications> results = new ArrayList<Applications>();
    ArrayList<String> gotPackagename = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        appfilter = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvApp);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(filenames, 0);
        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> applist = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
        Iterator<PackageInfo> it = applist.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            PackageInfo pk = (PackageInfo) it.next();
            results.add(new Applications(pk.applicationInfo
                    .loadIcon(packageManager), ""
                    + pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)));
            Log.i("AppName", "" + pk.applicationInfo.packageName);
            gotPackagename.add(pk.applicationInfo.packageName);
        }

        appfilter.setAdapter(new Customarrayadapter(this, results));
        appfilter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

but now I want to filter that the list will show only the games , is it possible?

Comment: I guess it is not possible!

Comment: really, is it not possible?

Comment: as when we are making a game. We never tell special in the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to set your app as "Game Type" in Android, so you could not filter apps by category.

I think, best solution - to parse all games packages (game name could be different because of phone localization) from Google Play and put that list in app and sometimes update it from your server. If you always got internet connection in your application you could send found apps list to server and server will return back games from that list. So, you need to write server code for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the package name of every app installed on the device and scrape the google play store to see if that app is in one of the games categories. But that's a bit hackish :).

Answer (score 1):

So first add this permission in your Manifest file

**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"**

it will return a boolean if it's true then your package name is from game category

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    binding = GameListBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    //get a list of installed apps.
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        Boolean b = checkAppIsGame(GameList.this,packageInfo.packageName);

        if(b){
            Toast.makeText(GameList.this, "This is Game "+ packageInfo.packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}

public static boolean checkAppIsGame(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        ApplicationInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Log.e("MyGame", "App Packagename is game : " + packageName);
            return info.category == ApplicationInfo.CATEGORY_GAME;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "is game 2 " + packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Util", "Package is game 2 : " + packageName);
            return (info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_IS_GAME) == ApplicationInfo.FLAG_IS_GAME;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("MyGame", "Package info Not Found For : " + packageName, e);

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.
Catagories are only for using in market Applications don't have any identifier to distinguish between app catagories.