# Android: Get list of installed in android device

Tags: android

Is there any way to get list of all games installed in an android device programmatically using java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically get the installed game list in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668443/how-to-programatically-get-the-installed-game-list-in-android)

Comment: is there any way to get list of android games package name?

Comment: No there is no way,check the ink above it's the best solution

Comment: no what i mean is how to get list of games package name from the play store?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the url

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name

From the source you will get something like

```
<span itemprop="genre">Shopping</span>
```

Or you can use [marketer-api](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).